# Why does a "block of imprimitivity" of an acting group generate a partition on the acted on set?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Godsil&Royle [Algebraic Graph Theory](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4613-0163-9) section 2.5 states (slightly paraphrased):

> Let $G$ be a transitive group acting on a set $V$. A nonempty subset $S$ of $V$ is a *block of imprimitivity* for G if for any element $g\in G$, either $g(S) = S$ or $g(S)\cap S = \emptyset$. Because $G$ is transitive, it is clear that the translates of $S$ form a partition on $V$.

Assuming "translates of $S$" refers to all the $g(S)$, I understand why those *cover* $V$.

**Question:** But how does it follow that any two $g(S)$ and $h(S)$, if not identical, have an empty intersection?

Put another way: why is the situation in this diagram not possible?

[image: overlapping g(S) and h(S)]

The diagram shall describe $x_1,x_2\in S$ both mapped to some $x\notin S$ by $g$ and $h$ respectively where otherwise $g(S)\neq h(S)$.
I tried to derive a contradiction from this situation, but failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $h^{-1}(g(S))$. On one hand, its intersection with $S$ is nonempty because $g(S)\cap h(S)$ is nonempty. On the other hand, it is not $S$: consider $y$ which is in $g(S)$ but not $h(S)$; then $h^{-1}(y)$ is not in $S$. (If such $y$ doesn't exist, then use the same reasoning with $g\leftrightarrow h$, which is possible unless $g(S)=h(S)$.)

Comment: Hmm, you say "$x$ is not in $h(S)$", but it is, per assumption.

Comment: @Harald sorry, this is not your $x$, this if a different element. Edited to avoid this notation collision.

Comment: I am sorry, I read it too quick and jumped to conclusions, but with the $y$ it is definitively easier to read :-)

Answer (score 3):

If $g(S)=f(S)$,  you are done. So, let's assume $g(S)\ne f(S)$.

- Case 1: $g(S)=S$ and $f(S)\ne S$; then, $g(S)\cap f(S)=S\cap f(S)=\emptyset$.
- Case 2: $g(S)\ne S$ and $f(S)=S$; then, $g(S)\cap f(S)=g(S)\cap S=\emptyset$.
- Case 3: $g(S)\ne S$ and $f(S)\ne S$; if $g(S)\cap f(S)\ne\emptyset$, then $\exists s',s''\in S$ such that $g(s')=f(s'')$, and hence $(f^{-1}g)(s')=s''\in S$; but then $(f^{-1}g)(S)=S$, because $S$ in a block of imprimitivity. Therefore, $g(S)=f(S)$: contradiction, and hence $g(S)\cap f(S)=\emptyset$.

So, $g(S)=f(S)$ or $g(S)\cap f(S)=\emptyset$.